# How to exclude a category returned by get_categories from function.php?

Tags: categories, filters

I have a plugin that create my website sitemap. It starts by getting all categories with `get_categories` and then gets all pages for each.
However I have one category that must not be included then I did that in the plugin code:

```
$args['exclude']=2;
$cats = get_categories( $args );
```

The problem is that if the plugin replace the file my modiofication will be deleted, I tried with that:

```
function exclude_cat($taxonomy, $args) {
    
    $args['exclude']=2;
    return $args;
}

add_filter('get_categories_taxonomy', 'exclude_cat', 10, 2);
```

But then no category is returned at all, I think I'm not using it correctly but I don't find examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find an appropriate filter in the `get_terms` function which is called by `get_categories`.

See source code https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L1247

We don't use any of the callback arguments in this case. We can use `array_filter` on the list of terms (WP_Term) objects. See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term/

This allows us to remove a term with a particular ID

```
add_filter( 'get_terms', function( $terms, $taxonomies, $args, $term_query ){

    return array_filter($terms, function( $term ) {
        return $term->term_id !== 2;
    });

}, 10, 4 );
```

Note that `get_categories` by default only returns categories which have posts assigned, you can change that by adding `hide_empty => false` to the `$args` array.